# Use only 2 screws for VESA mount

Tags: vesa

I bought a used aoc i2369vm, and when i checked the back of the screen, the top 2 vesa mount holes has no "screw holes" (i dont know the technical name of these), and i guess they fell inside the monitor.
I found out later that these holes were just attached (glued) to the plastic support, not to the actual metal chassis.

So is it safe to just use the 2 bottom vesa holes? 
and whats wrong with AOC people!

Comment: I would advice against it, because it puts a lot of stress on those two connections when the screen is upright or even tilted forwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, the weight of the display and vibration will cause the plastic near the lower side of the mount to separate. As this happens the display will appear to tilt downward more and more. Having the top screws in place (using the internal metal bracket that fell off) changes the way the weight is distributed so that the plastic is better able to sustain the display's weight without the plastic deforming excessively.

It will eventually fail but it's probably fine for now. Depending on how you treat the display or even how much your floor vibrates from walking and such, it could last like that from a few months to a few years.

Comment: But wont the top screw damage the plastic case? And ill probably move the display like 2-3 a day .. would gluing the "threaded inserts" like @David said help? and how can a manufacturer do such thing in the first place ...

Comment: @OuerghiYassine That's why there's a threaded metal bracket behind the plastic (the bit you said fell inside the monitor). I don't think the inserts will help. They're usually designed to mount using a compression fit and will pull out. If you're inclined and it's out of warranty, I'd suggest taking off the display's cover and fishing out the wandering piece you're supposed to using. If it's within your return period, perhaps just exchanging it for a replacement will work.

Comment: But how can that "small" piece hold all that weight, anyways, it is still under warranty, but its a minor problem, so ill wait until its out of warranty and open it.

Comment: Well, it just has to hold it until the warranty is done, right? =P There are two main forces that need to be dealt with: shearing and torque. For torque, you have the top and bottom mounts but, critically, it's the top mounts help prevent torque damage. Had you lost the bottom mounts instead of the top, you'd still have the same essential configuration to mitigate torque due to gravity: the bottom edge pushing against the display and the top edge w/bracket pulling on the display. But as it is, you only have the bottom mounts so the same torque is confined to a much smaller area.

Comment: @OuerghiYassine: If it's still under warranty, why would you not get the defect repaired or the monitor replaced?  That's sort of the purpose of the warranty.

Comment: The monitor came from a whole other country, it would be useless to ship it all the way through for that ...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably fine.  Maybe use some glue or silicon caulking in the top holes and tapping screws in the top screw holes for stability.

Comment: @OerghiYassine: The bottom screws will probably hold the weight if they actually screw into something substantial.  The risk is the torque, especially if you pull on the top to adjust it.  If you're comfortable opening the case, look inside for threaded inserts (if they fell out inside, you don't want those loose in there anyway).  Look for a way to glue those or some nuts to the back of the holes.  That will give you something to fasten to.  If that isn't practical, I'd go farther with David's glue/caulking suggestion and supplement the bottom screws by adhering the whole mount to the back.